# move files with extension from a subdirectory of directory to another subdirectory with the same name of another directory

Tags: bash, copy, move, subdirectory

I would like to move or copy some files with a particular extension that are missing in a new data update provided into another new directory preserving the subdirectories structure. I would like to do it with bash commands. I am using a MacBook Pro.

I got a structure like this:

```
/dir1/a/b/c/file1.json
/dir1/a/b/k/file2.json
/dir1/a/x/z/file3.json
/dir1/a/x/z/file4.zip
```

I would like to move ONLY those files ending with .json into another directory preserving the subdirectories. Regarding the other directory, it can contain other files in the subfolders.

In the new directory there can be also different files:

```
/dir2/a/b/c/file9.HTML
/dir2/a/b/k/file1.RAR
/dir2/a/x/z/file3.xls
/dir2/a/x/z/file4.XML
```

The movements will be like:

```
/dir1/a/b/c/file1.json -> /dir2/a/b/c/file1.json
/dir1/a/b/k/file2.json -> /dir2/a/b/k/file2.json
/dir1/a/x/z/file3.json -> /dir2/a/x/z/file3.json
/dir1/a/x/z/file4.zip -> no action as it is not .json
```

So the final status of the structure will be this:

```
/dir2/a/b/c/file9.HTML
/dir2/a/b/c/file1.json

/dir2/a/b/k/file1.RAR
/dir2/a/b/k/file2.json

/dir2/a/x/z/file3.xls
/dir2/a/x/z/file3.json

/dir2/a/x/z/file4.XML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find + gnu-cp` command with `--parents` option:

```
find /dir1 -name '*.json' -exec cp --parents -t /dir2/ {} +
```

As per `man cp`:

```
--parents      use full source file name under DIRECTORY
```

Which will basically create same sub-directory structure in `/dir2` for each `*.json` file as in `/dir1`.